# JAXB Unmarshall error

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using JAXB on my project, but from time to time, I face some problems that I can't solve. I have setup my environment like this:

Armor Class

```
package com.fortresswars.entity.component;

@XmlType(name = "armor", namespace = "http://fortresswars.com")
public class ArmorComponent extends AbstractComponent
```

package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(xmlns = @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://fortresswars.com", prefix = "fw"), elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED, namespace = "http://fortresswars.com")
package com.fortresswars.entity.component;
```

The generated schema header is almost correct:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://fortresswars.com" xmlns:fw="http://fortresswars.com" xmlns:tns="http://fortresswars.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

The only thing I didn't like is that TNS prefix that JAXB puts there and I can't remove. I'm using an ant task (`com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask`), and I remember reading somewhere that this was the problem.

The rest of the generated scheme follows below. I'll show only the relevant part about armor:

```
<xs:complexType name="armor">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:abstractComponent">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="value" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="type" type="tns:armor-type" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And the element that is using the armor component:

```
  <xs:complexType name="character">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:thing">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="armor" type="tns:armor"/>
            <xs:element name="model" type="tns:model"/>
            <xs:element name="status" type="tns:status"/>
            <xs:element name="costs" type="tns:costs"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

To test this, I created a XML Document (see the TNS prefix, I need to put it, or the `fw` prefix, along with the xmlns:fw also).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:character xmlns:tns="http://fortresswars.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="/home/shirkit/jMonkeyProjects/Fortress Wars/Core/schema/full.xsd">

<armor>
<value>5</value>
<type>NORMAL</type>
</armor>

</tns:character>
```

But when I'm unmarshalling this document, here's the error I get:

```
Exception: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"armor"). Expected elements are <{http://fortresswars.com}armor>,<{http://fortresswars.com}attacks>,<{http://fortresswars.com}costs>,<{http://fortresswars.com}model>,<{http://fortresswars.com}abilities>,<{http://fortresswars.com}status>,<{http://fortresswars.com}movement>
```

I have setup elementFormDefault to UNQUALIFIED, and even though this doesn't work. Why I'm getting this exception? And can I remove TNS prefix from the generated schema?

Comment: i don't understand what you are expecting to happen?  everything is working the way you have currently defined it to work.

Comment: No @jtahlborn , I'm getting an exception while trying to unmarshall the document I created. The exception message is written there, it's the last code block.

Comment: you said it works with the tns prefix?

Comment: I said it is there, and without it the XML is invalid, as it doesn't recognise that is a CHARACTER. But with it, the exception that is thrown is described at the last code block. That exception is giving for the code above it, WITH the TNS prefix.

Comment: @jtahlborn forgot to add your tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a namespace prefix for elements of http://fortresswars.com you need to prefix all elements with it, not only `character`. So this should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:character 
    xmlns:tns="http://fortresswars.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="/home/shirkit/jMonkeyProjects/Fortress Wars/Core/schema/full.xsd">
    <tns:armor>
        <tns:value>5</tns:value>
        <tns:type>NORMAL</tns:type>
    </tns:armor>
</tns:character>
```

The `tns` prefix used in the schema is unrelated to what you use as prefix for XML text that you unmarshal. You may choose any other in `xmlns:whatyoulike="http://fortresswars.com"`. The key that connects the elements in the XML document to the definitions in the schema file is the namespace URI, in your case "http://fortresswars.com". If you define your namespace as default namespace, you can omit the prefix on every element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<character 
    xmlns="http://fortresswars.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="/home/shirkit/jMonkeyProjects/Fortress Wars/Core/schema/full.xsd">
    <armor>
        <value>5</value>
        <type>NORMAL</type>
    </armor>
</character>
```

The namespace prefix in the XSD file helps to avoid name clashes if you wan't to use the schema file together with other schema files that define types or elements with the same name. It does not force you to use it in the xml files you want to unmarshal.

On the other hand, when you marhshal objects to XML, the file `package-info.java` defines what prefix JAXB uses, but this only works in recent versions of JAXB and it's not always easy to assure that the correct version is in use when your code runs. But you may use a `NamespacePrefixMapper` to control that.